# How to make all buttons in row aligned with button that has dynamic height

Tags: html, css, reactjs, button

I am displaying data coming from an API on a row of buttons in React. For one of the buttons, I am setting the width to be 200px. The button dynamically changes the height to fit the data in if it goes past the 200px limit. However, my other buttons become unaligned with this button's height. How do I make all of them aligned no matter if the width pixel limit is reached or not?

```
'& .myLongTextButton': {
  width: '200px'
},
'& .myShortTextButton': {
  width: '50px'
}

<Button className="myLongTextButton">{data.long_text}
</Button>
<Button className="myShortTextButton">{data.short_text}
</Button>
```

Comment: How can we guess without a producible example? How can we know the `Button`'s styling?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is wrap both buttons with a flexbox container. For example:

```
'& .container': {
  display: inline-flex;
}
'& .myLongTextButton': {
  width: '200px'
},
'& .myShortTextButton': {
  width: '50px'
}

<div classname="container">
 <Button className="myLongTextButton">{data.long_text}
 </Button>
 <Button className="myShortTextButton">{data.short_text}
 </Button>
</div>
```

Comment: @bag02832 then upvote and accept the answer please 